# setting label expressions causing duplicate labels

Tags: arcobjects, labeling, vb.net

kind of new to VB.NET.

Trying to set my label expression for a layer. Essentially a user picks a layer from a combo box, hits a button, expression is applied on the layer and then the single shp file is converted to annotation. my issue is it seems to work for 75%. I am labeling creeks and want to label the [TYPE] vs the [NAME]. It seems to label the Type for most but for whatever reason there are a few names being labeled as well. Did I screw up some where?

it seems to label the DEFAULT field as well as my expression when I just want it to label my expression.

```vb
Shared Sub ConvertLabelsToAnnotationSingleLayerMapAnno(ByVal pMap As IMap, ByVal layerIndex As Integer)
    Dim pConvertLabelsToAnnotation As IConvertLabelsToAnnotation = New ConvertLabelsToAnnotationClass()
    Dim pTrackCancel As ITrackCancel = New CancelTrackerClass()
    'Change global level options for the conversion by sending in different parameters to the next line.
    pConvertLabelsToAnnotation.Initialize(pMap, esriAnnotationStorageType.esriMapAnnotation, _
                                          esriLabelWhichFeatures.esriVisibleFeatures, True, _
                                          pTrackCancel, Nothing)
    Dim pLayer As ILayer = pMap.Layer(layerIndex)
    Dim pGeoFeatureLayer As IGeoFeatureLayer = pLayer

    If Not pGeoFeatureLayer Is Nothing Then
        Dim pAnnotateLPC As IAnnotateLayerPropertiesCollection
        pAnnotateLPC = pGeoFeatureLayer.AnnotationProperties
        Dim pAnnotateLP As IAnnotateLayerProperties
        pAnnotateLP = New LabelEngineLayerProperties
        Dim pLabelELP1 As ILabelEngineLayerProperties2
        pLabelELP1 = pAnnotateLP
        pLabelELP1.Expression = String.Format("[Type]")
        pAnnotateLPC.Add(pAnnotateLP)
        pGeoFeatureLayer.DisplayAnnotation = True

        Dim pFeatureClass As IFeatureClass = pGeoFeatureLayer.FeatureClass
        'Add the layer information to the converter object. Specify the parameters of the output annotation feature class here as well.
        pConvertLabelsToAnnotation.AddFeatureLayer(pGeoFeatureLayer, pGeoFeatureLayer.Name + "_Anno", _
                                                   Nothing, Nothing, False, False, False, False, False, "")
        'Do the conversion.
        pConvertLabelsToAnnotation.ConvertLabels()
        'Turn off labeling for the layer converted.
        pGeoFeatureLayer.DisplayAnnotation = False
        'Refresh the map to update the display.
        Dim pActiveView As IActiveView = pMap
        pActiveView.Refresh()
    End If
End SubationSingleLayerMapAnno(pMap, cmbAOA.SelectedIndex)
```

Comment: If anyone comes across this https://geonet.esri.com/thread/40373 seems to have solved my issue.

Comment: It might be better to 'answer' your own question and then accept it. It will archive as an answered question instead of an unanswered one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

geonet.esri.com/thread/40373 has the working code here.